# How to edit Inno Setup directive without recompiling everything

Tags: inno-setup

I forgot to add one line (`DisableProgramGroupPage=yes`) to `[Setup]`. Is there a way to add it there without recompiling the whole thing? It weights 8GB so I'd want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably possible. The `DisableProgramGroupPage` compiles into one specific byte in the target binary. Though if you change it, you will have to recalculate installer checksum and update it too in the binary.

I do not think there are any easy to use ready-made tool for this. So in the end, it would take you for sure a lot more time than recompiling the script.